# Execute conda activate prompt: "The system cannot find the specified path"

Tags: windows, anaconda, conda

1. "The system cannot find the specified path."
2. Open "Anaconda Poweshhell" and error message "The system cannot find the specified path."
3. Repeatedly reinstalled Anaconda
4. The path does not have Chinese characters.
5. Executing "activate. bat" separately is also this prompt
6. Opening Anaconda Prompt also prompts "The system cannot find the specified path."
7. After online tutorials, Anaconda Powershell Prompt can now be used normally.
8. Conda init has already been executed